# how to return T type from static method in C#?

Tags: c#, static

I want to use `static` member in my class and I don't want to use `<T>` from my `static` method.

```
public class Person : AQuaryTable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class User : AQuaryTable
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
public class AQuaryTable
{
    public static List<T> SelectAll<T>()//static this T tmp
    {
        var getType = typeof(T);
        return null;
    }
}
```

use this:

```
var listOfPersons1 = Person.SelectAll<Person>();//don't want use type <Person>
var listOfUsers1 = User.SelectAll<User>();//don't want use type <User>

//I want to use this code:
var listOfPersons = Person.SelectAll();//exception 
var listOfUsers = User.SelectAll();//exception
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, designing a pattern that relies on inheritance of `static` methods is not a good idea but, if you must, you could try this idea:

```
public class Person : QueryTable<Person>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User : QueryTable<User>
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public abstract class QueryTable
{
    // TODO: Write as much as you can, here.

    protected static List<T> SelectAll<T>()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public abstract class QueryTable<T> : QueryTable
{
    public static List<T> SelectAll()
    {
        return QueryTable.SelectAll<T>();

        // Note: You could just implement this inline, here.
    }

    // TODO: Put stuff that is specific to T, here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make `SelectAll` an extension method

```
public static List<T> SelectAll<T>(this T source) where T : AQuaryTable
```

Then you should be able to call it like this:

```
var listOfPersons = Person.SelectAll();
```

Note: You need to declare `SelectAll` method in a `static` class.

Comment: thank you for replay.
can i use this without argument?

Comment: It really is bad practice to implement a class' behaviour as extension methods. Extension methods were added to facilitate `Linq`, not to facilitate poor code.

Comment: This answer is not helpful because you can't call the extension method without an instance so it violates the original declaration that `SelectAll` was `static` and you'd have to write that extension method on another class, which requires another pointless static class, too.

Answer (score 0):

Make it an instance method and make the base class generic:

```
public class AQuaryTable<T>
{
    public List<T> SelectAll()
    {
    }
}

public class User : AQuaryTable<User>
{

}
```